# String building recursively

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Consider a Class **DataHolder**

Attributes:

> 1. Name: data name
> 2. Value: value (comma separated)

My input is a list of DataHolders.
eg:

> List of DataHolder:
> DataHolder1: name:A, value:**1,2**
>
> DataHolder2: name:B, value:**X**
>
> DataHolder3: name:C, value:**a,b,c**

I want to build a list of strings like this from the data:
**1Xa
1Xb
1Xc
2Xa
2Xb
2Xc**

I came up with a logic using reccursion.

```
 void formString(List<DataHolder> dataHolders, int currentIndex, String formedString, int size){
 if(currentIndex == size){
      // store formedString in a list and return
 }
 else{
      1. get value from dataholder
      2. String tokenize the value
      3. iterate over the tokenized value and for each tokenized value call 

 formString(dataHolders, currentIndex + 1, formedString + tokeizedValue, 
 size)
 }
 }
```

My code works and it produces the expected output.
1Xa
1Xb
1Xc
2Xa
2Xb
2Xc

is there a better way to do this other than the recursive method?

Comment: Given how big the result can get, I would highly recommend returning an `Iterator` object that goes through the resulting list without having to generate all of it in memory.